# Is it possible to use mysql with javascriptl?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I know that you can't directly use them them together. How can I use them together?

Comment: It's not recomended.

Comment: What do you recommend as an alternative to javascript?

Comment: what are you trying to do with javascript in MySQL !! could you clarify more please

Comment: You can use it directly with server side js implementations, such as node.js. Otherwise you will need another server side technology (php, python, ruby, asp.net, etc) to connect the database with the client side js.

Comment: Just google "nodejs" and "MySQL". https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: NodeJS or browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you're running JavaScript server-side (such as with node.js). This won't be possible directly with client-side JavaScript, however (i.e., in a web-browser). For that, you'd have to add an extra communication layer such as a REST web service to send your data from the browser and persist it on a server running MySQL.